# How to verify the content of ZipFile before saving to disk

Tags: java, file-upload, upload, zip

I have an application that requires a user to upload a zipfile containing xml report file among other files.

What I want to do is, to verify it is a zip, then open and check if there is an xml file, and verify some few nodes which are required in that xml.

I want to do this before I save this zipfile to a disk/filesystem, and withought creating a temporary file. I will only save the file if it passes the validation.

I am using Spring `multipart CommonsMultipartFile` to manage uploads.

The application is using Java, jsp, tomcat

Thanks.

Comment: Check http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/Readfileswithinazipfile.htm, they show several ZIP operations using Java that could be useful.

Comment: this doesn't seem very safe.  if you receive the entire contents of the file on the server and keep them in memory, you risk running the server out of memory.  writing streams of unknown size to a temp file before working with them is almost _always_ the best option for a robust server implementation.

Comment: @jtahlborn I guess he can set a file max size and check so that the upload does not exceed the allowed file size. Seem unnecessary to save on disk first if only small files are accepted.

Comment: Also check http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/compression/

Comment: @PederN - i didn't see any indication that the OP was only accepting small files.

Comment: @jtahlborn I have the overhead file size check, because we do know the average size of the file to expect. It should not be over 3Mb. So the interface won't allow any file above that size.

Answer (score 1):

See my comment on the OP about the wisdom of buffering the entire file in memory.

One quick *first* check for a valid zip file would be to check the first 4 bytes for the appropriate "magic" bytes.  a zip file should start with the first 4 bytes `{(byte)0x50, (byte)0x4b, (byte)0x03, (byte)0x04}`.  the only way to *really* check it, however, is to attempt to unzip it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I did not know this method of checking the "magic byte" I was using the contentType method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether a file is a ZIP file, perhaps you can use getContentType() method of the `URLConnection` class? Something like this:

```
URL u = new URL(fileUrl);
URLConnection uc = u.openConnection();
String type = uc.getContentType();
```

But it would be much faster to detect the [magic bytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) which, for the ZIP format, are `50 4B`.

Comment: This is not what he is asking for? He wants to take an uploaded ZIP and check for a valid XML (some kind of manifest?) before saving it permanently.

Comment: that only verifies that you got the bytes the client sent.  it doesn't check that the file sent is _actually_ a zip file.

Comment: Ah, I apologise then - misunderstanding. :)

Comment: I've removed previous content of my answer, and wrote a new answer.